# Navigation control for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project for dealing with buildings and environment classifications. Now i would like to create a navigation control that helps my user.

The idea is that on top of the every page there will be a vista like folder structure path that explains where the user is. To make an example

Start > Country1 > State2

City1
City2
City3
...

And if the user click on a city in the list we get this page:

Start > Country1 > State2 > City3

Building1
Building2
Building3
...

The tricky part is that you should also be able to list all the buildings in the database without choosing Country and State before. Like this:

Start

City1
City2
City3
...

And when you click on a city you should get this page:

Start > City2

Building1
Building2
...

---

Anyone have a suggestion on how I should solve this. I tried to create a navigation stack and push states to this stack from my controlleractions but whenever i used the browsers back and forward buttons the navigation stack gets inaccurate.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want breadcrumbs which show the browser history, or do you want the position of the current page relative to, say, a site map? These are two very different things.

Comment: Relative to a site map, the problem is that you can get from node A to node B in more than one way!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you can click on any of the levels in the navigation tree.  In that case I would have it be the same no matter how you got to a particular node, that is it should represent the path to that node.  This would make it relatively easy, since you need only follow the foreign key relationships until you get to the top level to build the path.  Since you always have the Start element as the root, the user can easily reset themselves back to the beginning.

Comment: I think it's not the right design.  The url and your navigation path should reflect the path to the object.  It's both easier and less confusing to the user because it's consistent.

Comment: Yeah I had to redesign according to you suggestion. Thanx.